# angular2-meteor feature module import error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined extractStyleUrls

Tags: angular-meteor, angular2-modules

created angular2 feature module when import module to main app.module, getting below error
*`modules.js?hash=83df0dc…:35050 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedextractStyleUrls @ modules.js?hash=83df0dc…:35050(anonymous function) @ modules.js?hash=83df0dc…:38274DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeStylesheet @ modules.js?hash=83df0dc…:38273DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeLoadedTemplate @ modules.js?hash=83df0dc…:38203DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateSync @ modules.js?hash=83df0dc…:38178DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplate @ modules.js?hash=83df0dc…:38155CompileMetadataResolver._loadDirectiveMetadata @ modules.js?hash=83df0dc…:42474(anonymous function) @ modules.js?hash=83df0dc…:42650CompileMetadataResolver.loadNgModuleDirectiveAndPipeMetadata @ modules.js?hash=83df0dc…:42649(anonymous function) @ modules.js?hash=83df0dc…:51875JitCompiler._loadModules @ modules.js?hash=83df0dc…:51874JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ modules.js?hash=83df0dc…:51829JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ modules.js?hash=83df0dc…:51795PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone @ modules.js?hash=83df0dc…:61199PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule @ modules.js?hash=83df0dc…:61174(anonymous function) @ main.ts:10maybeReady @ meteor.js?hash=e3f53db…:809loadingCompleted @ meteor.js?hash=e3f53db…:821`*

I'm new to angular 2 and meteor,please help me.